# How to display the exact numbers specified in .tickValues()

Tags: d3.js

The values in the ticks are rounded up, but i want them as they're in the array, could someone help me figure out how to fix this?

```
var xAxisLegend = d3
    .axisBottom(xScaleLegend)
    .tickValues([2.8, 3.9, 5.0, 6.1, 7.2, 8.3, 9.5, 10.6, 11.7, 12.8]);
```

[Here is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/65fqp91m/2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [tickFormat](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis#axis_tickFormat) to show more decimal places

```
var xAxisLegend = d3
    .axisBottom(xScaleLegend)
    .tickValues([2.8, 3.9, 5.0, 6.1, 7.2, 8.3, 9.5, 10.6, 11.7, 12.8])
    .tickFormat(d3.format(",.1f"));
```

Here's a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v9yn07ej/) and [formatting docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-format/blob/master/README.md)